# Flutter Center Title Not True Pt. 2

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I used centerTitle successfully in the past, but it is not working this time. I get Unexpected token ';' error at bottom of page. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: bgcolor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: hdrcolor,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
              'My App Name',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans', color: hdrtxtcolor, fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ProfilePageWidget(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: txtcolor,
                  size: 24,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Comment: The error is  Unexpected token ';' at bottom of page

Comment: You forgot to add , (comma) in last third line

Comment: share your full code of this page.

Comment: i added the comma in last third line, but did not fix

Comment: return complete with ';' instead of comma(,) in your last line

Comment: in last line, i changed comma to semi-colon but did not fix

Comment: share your full code it would be helped to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer **AppBar** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(
      'My App Name',
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Noto Sans', fontSize: 28),
    ),
    actions: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            size: 24,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Your result screen ->[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last , with ; like that

```
return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: bgcolor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: hdrcolor,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
              'My App Name',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans', color: hdrtxtcolor, fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ProfilePageWidget(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: txtcolor,
                  size: 24,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ); // <--------
```

You are returning a Scaffold and the return statement needs to end in a ;